# Twig function/filter with no input?

Tags: twig, slim, slim-3

I'm using Slim 3 and Slim Twig-View. I want to add a Twig function (or filter, not sure what is the difference?) which generates a random string, and doesn't take any input.

I was able to add a filter like this:

```
$twig->getEnvironment()->addFilter(
   new \Twig_Filter('guid', function(){ return generateGUID(); })
);
```

But I can't seem to use it without providing some dummy input:

```
{{ 0|guid }} This will work
{{ guid }} This will not work
```

How can I use my `guid` filter/function without providing any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter always apply on something, it **filters** something.

What you want is a function, indeed.
The [extending Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html) page of the documentation is an incredible source of information on that matter.

At first glance, I would even have said *you should define a tag for this* but the documentation on the tag, explicitly says:

> - If your tag generates some output, use a **function** instead.

<sup>*Source: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#tags*</sup>

---

So indeed, in order to define a [function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#functions):

> Functions are defined in the exact same way as filters, but you need to create an instance of `\Twig\TwigFunction`:
>
> ```
> $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader); 
> $function = new \Twig\Twig_Function('function_name', function () {
>     // ... 
> }); 
> $twig->addFunction($function);
> ```

---

So more specifically for you:

```
$container->get('view')->getEnvironment()->addFunction(
   new Twig_SimpleFunction('guid', function(){ return generateGUID(); })
);
```

Will be accessible via:

```
{{ guid() }}
```

---

***Other worth reading***:

- [extending twig](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/features/templates.html#extending-twig), in Slim documentation
- you can achieve the same with a [macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html)